# iOS: Get Audio from AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

**Disclaimer** New to AVAudioRecorder

**What I'm doing** I'm working on an app that uses the iPhone microphone to record sound. After the sound is recorded, I need to convert the sound (should be AVAsset, right?) into NSData to send to our backend.

**What's the issue** The issue is I am not sure how to "get" the audio that is supposed to be recorded with the AVAudioRecorder. AVAudioRecorder has a delegate method called `- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *) aRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag`. I would have expected the actually AVAsset that contains the audio to be passed from this delegate method, but it does not. What it does give me is the `aRecorder` object that has a `.url` property on it. When I NSLog the url from the passed `aRecorder`, it shows up. In fact I can NSLog the length of the file in the code below:

```
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *) aRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    DLog (@"audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully: %@",aRecorder);

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:aRecorder.url options:nil];
    CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
    float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);

    NSLog(@"asset length = %f", audioDurationSeconds); //Logs 7.051 seconds, so I know it's "there".

    self.audioURL = aRecorder.url;
}
```

**Problem** When I pass `self.audioURL` to the next viewController's `self.mediaURL` and try to grab the file from the AssetLibrary (similarly to how I did before), the asset is not returned from the AssetLibrary (even though when I `po self.mediaURL` it indeed logs the correct url:

```
if (self.mediaURL) {

            ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [assetLibrary assetForURL:self.mediaURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

                if (asset) {
                    // This block does NOT get called...

                    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                    Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc((long)rep.size);
                    NSUInteger buffered =[rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(long)rep.size error:nil];

                    NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
                    body = [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

                    [dataToSendToServer setObject:body forKey:@"audioData"];
                }

            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"FAILED TO ACCESS AUDIO FROM URL: %@!", self.mediaURL);
            }];

        }

        else {

            NSLog(@"NO AUDIO DATA!");
        }
}
```

Because I am new to AVAudioRecorder, perhaps I am just not designing this flow correctly. Could anyone help me out in getting the actual audio data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVAudioRecorder records to a file, not to the Asset Library.

So you can simply read the data from that file.

Comment: Where is that file stored in the device? And with the `self.audioURL` that I am passing around, will that allow me to access the actual file from anywhere (from any application on the device)?

Comment: You decided the file location when you Inited the AVAudioRecorder. Yes you can access it in your app

Comment: So can I do something like `NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.mediaURL];` and that's all I have to do to convert it to NSData?

Comment: Exactly! That's how you do it.

Comment: Thanks. One more question if I could ask... What If I wanted to use the method `dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer` so that I could eventually do "Pause" and "Resume" uploads based on the bytes remaining?

Comment: Ok I did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092220/ios-getting-byte-data-from-file