# Getting byte Data from File

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

**WHAT IM DOING** I am trying to get an audio file (could be up to an hour long. eg. a Podcast) that I've recorded with AVAudioRecorder to be uploaded to our backend. In addition to being uploaded to the server it needs to be able to be "Paused" and "Resumed" if the user chooses. Because of this, I believe, I need to use `dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer` on the `NSData` class to achieve this.

**WHERE IM AT** I know for a fact I can get the data with using the passed `self.mediaURL` property:

```
if (self.mediaURL) {

    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.mediaURL];

    if (audioData) {

        [payloadDic setObject:audioData forKey:@"audioData"];
    }

}
```

However, this will not give me the desired functionality. I am trying to keep track of the bytes uploaded so that I can resume if the user pauses.

**QUESTION** How can I use the provided `self.mediaURL` so that I can retrieve the file and be able to calculate the byte length like this example?

```
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc((long)audioFile.size);
NSUInteger buffered =[rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(long)rep.size error:nil];

NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
body = [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making things more complicated for yourself by trying to reinvent the wheel, use what the system gives you. NSURLSession lets you do a [background upload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html). You hand the task to the session (created using the background session configuration) and just walk away. The upload takes place in pieces, when it can. No "pause" or "resume" needed; the system takes care of everything. Your app doesn't even have to be running. If authentication is needed, your app will be woken up in the background as required. This architecture is just made for the situation you describe.

If the problem is that you want random access to file data without having to read the whole thing into a massive NSData, use NSFileHandle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But our team explicitly wants a Pause button to stop the upload and a Resume button to start the upload again from the spot that the file was left off at. So our API is going to be designed to send us back a Header once the user clicks "Resume" that will contain the last byte that the upload stopped at, then I will need to take that information and plug it into the `dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer` method to start uploading again from the right position in data.

Comment: Well, an upload task is not resumable so you'll end up doing all the work yourself...

Comment: Added a mention of NSFileHandle to my answer; this may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll take a look at that in time and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Well its been well over a year since this posting. I believe we dropped the whole resume feature all together. But for being awesome, you get a checkmark.